# How to remove a line starting and ending with different strings from a file

Tags: sed, grep, cut

I have a file like this:

```
@          IN     NS                 ns1.riodomain.com.
@          IN     A                  192.175.3.255
@          IN     MX     10          root@ns1.riodomain.com.
mail       IN     A                  192.164.2.228
ns1        IN     A                  192.164.2.333
```

After executing i need to get as follows

```
@          IN     A                  192.175.3.255
@          IN     MX     10          root@ns1.riodomain.com.
mail       IN     A                  192.164.2.228
ns1        IN     A                  192.164.2.333
```

I need to remove the first line with specific pattern.
Can anyone help?

Comment: why has IP `192.164.2.228` changed to `192.168.1.213`?

Comment: it was a mistake

Comment: are there empty strings between the lines?

Comment: no empty strings between lines

Comment: are there any other lines in the file or it's just about removing the first line?

Comment: i need to delete line that start with @ and ends with string like riodomain.com. or 192.164.2.333

Comment: *start with **@** and ends with string like **riodomain.com.*** - but you have `@ IN MX 10 root@ns1.riodomain.com.` in your expected output, shouldn't be  removed?

Comment: yes, it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @ IN MX 10 root@ns1.riodomain.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement(literally):

> I need to delete line that start with **@** and ends with string like
>   **riodomain.com.** or **192.164.2.333**

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i '/^@.*\(riodomain\.com\.\|192\.164\.2\.333\)$/d' file
```

Now, the file contents should look like:

```
@ IN A 192.175.3.255
mail IN A 192.164.2.228
ns1 IN A 192.164.2.333
```

---

`-i` - option, to modify file *in place*

`/d` - flag, tells to delete the lines matched the pattern

Comment: how to remove the first line only using the parameters

Comment: @Rio, you have changed your mind, how that? to delete the first line it's enough to apply: `sed -i '1d' file`

Comment: your requirement is unclear, you said you need *to delete the first line* but you *dont know the line number*. You are changing your logic on the fly

Comment: I said that i have a file and the file contains the lines mentioned above.

Comment: i need to delete the line starts with @ and ends with riodomain.com

Comment: unfortunately that line was the first line.so i said the first line to be deleted

Comment: why the second line of your expected result `@          IN     MX     10          root@ns1.riodomain.com.` is not removed(as it *starts with @ and ends with riodomain.com*) ???

Comment: the script should not remove the **@ IN MX 10 root@ns1.riodomain.com.** only the  @          IN     NS                 ns1.riodomain.com.

Comment: it should not be removed

Comment: only the first line should be removed

Comment: @Rio, so use `sed -i '/@ *IN *NS *ns1.riodomain.com./d' file`